# The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Tags: flutter, oop, dart

I am trying to get price instance member from another class by passing that in navigator as

```html
 Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => InfoPage(
                              image: image,
                              tag: tag,
                              name: name,
                              category: category,
                              price: price,
                            )));

// my price is defined inside a var products as shown below

 var products = [
{
  "price": " 100",
  "imageLink": "images/pd.jpg",
  "tag": "one",
  "name": "product_1",
  "category": "combo",
},
]
```

The instance member 'prodPrice' and 'widget.price' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

This is the error message I am getting I tried initializing my instance variable but that didnt work plz help

```html
    import import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class InfoPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final String image;
      final String name;
      final String price;
      final String category;
      final String tag;

      const InfoPage(
          {Key key, this.image, this.name, this.tag, this.category, this.price})
          : super(key: key);
      @override
      _InfoPageState createState() => _InfoPageState();
    }

    class _InfoPageState extends State<InfoPage> {
   String prodPrice;   
      void initState() {
    super.initState();
    prodPrice = int.parse(widget.price);
  }
      
      var prodPrice;
      dynamic total = widget.price; 
      dynamic prodPrice = widget.price*2; 

// the above 2 lines are giving error while using widget.price and also prodPrice.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to their value on initState function

```
class _InfoPageState extends State<InfoPage> {   
   var prodPrice;
   dynamic total; 
   
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    total = widget.price; 
    prodPrice = int.parse(widget.price);
  }  
}
```

Also You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999971/flutter-instance-member-0-can-t-be-accessed-using-static-access).

Answer (score 1):

put them in a function and call it when ever you want

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  prodPrice = int.parse(widget.price);
}

dynamic total;
dynamic prodPrice;

getinit() {
  total = widget.price;
  prodPrice = widget.price * 2;
}
```